# how to modify a class array element via reference

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I can't figure out how to do this without pointers:

// hash table with seperate chaining

```
class HashTbl {
  class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
  }

  private Node tbl[];

  HashTbl(int size) {
    tbl[] = new Node[size * 1.25];
  }

  public int insert(int item) {
    // insert data
  }

  public Node lookup(int item) {
    // search for item in the hashtable
    // the item was found at array index 'idx'
    return tbl[idx];
  } 

  public int remove (int item) {
    Node n = lookup(item);
    n = null;  // <--- this obviously doesn't work, what i want to do is set tbl[idx] to null
  }

}
```

Setting the local reference variable to null doesn't affect the actual array.
In c++ i would return a pointer to the array element so that i can set the array element to Null via the pointer.
Now, there are no pointers in Java, so how can i make this work?

Update:
returning an the array index or using a separate function that returns a the matched index are 2 possible workarounds.
But i am not just looking for a solution to this particular program. 
What about this problem in general?

Comment: Java doesn't have pointers, but you can pass in an array and an index together, and clear out that slot in the array.

Comment: Chris, i think i will go with your solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
tbl[item] = null;
```

Update: I missed the fact that there is some omitted code in `lookup()`. Do this instead:

```
private int findIdx(int item) {
  // search for item in the hashtable
  // the item was found at array index 'idx'
  return idx;
} 

public Node lookup(int item) {
  return tbl[findIdx(item)];
}   

public int remove (int item) {
  tbl[findIdx(item)] = null;
}
```

Comment: I think he intentionally omitted the irrelevant way of finding out `idx` in the `lookup` method. I believe that generally **`idx != item`**.

Comment: Yeap, item should match the data field in the Node object.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way: have `lookup` return `idx` and use that in `remove`. Alternatively, if you need the `lookup` method to be `public` in that form, make a new, private method that returns the index.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int lookup(int item) {
  // search item in hash, return index
  return idx;
} 

public int remove (int item) {
  int idx = lookup(item);
  tbl[idx] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use ArrayList other than common array.

```
List<Node> tbl = new ArrayList<Node>();
```

look up the java manual for detail.